# Center UIButton to View

Tags: uibutton, imageview, center, move, rootview

I'm trying to center a UIButton to rootView. I've tried with this code:

```
self.startNewCross.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.startNewCross.frame.origin.y);
```

but it doesn't work, then I've tried to center the background image to UIButton

```
self.startNewCross.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

but the uibutton is fixed on left. How to move the uibutton?
I've other elements and the I move it without problem

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`[self.startNewCross setCenter:self.view.center]`

This Will Helps You....